# Ajax success function won't execute

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, cordova, http

I have an apache cordova project where I'm trying to post form data from the client to the database. I can see the json I send going out to my API which then sends the data to the DAL and then to the database. The entry correctly updates the table and then returns a 1 or -1 based on whether or not a previous entry exists. This value is then sent to the client. I can see the exact response being sent back, but my ajax success function won't fire.

Ajax:

```
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var info = {
            Username: $("#username").val(),
            Password: $("#password").val(),
            Firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
            Lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
            Email: $("#email").val()
        };

        info = JSON.stringify(info);

        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            url: "http://localhost:57207/api/User/RegisterUser",
            data: info,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(input) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
            }
        })
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JObject RegisterUser(JObject obj)
    {
        RegisterUsers user = new RegisterUsers();
        user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterUsers>(((JProperty)obj.First).Name);
        var temp = DataAccessLayer.RegisterUser(user.Username, user.Password, user.Firstname, user.Lastname, user.Email, null, null);
        JObject jobj = new JObject();
        jobj.Add("output", temp.ToString());

        return jobj;
    }
```

I have been using fiddler to check my response and request, and here is the raw data:

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:57207/api/User/RegisterUser HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57207
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 125
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:4400/test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"Username":"johndoe","Password":"password!!!","Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe","Email":"johndoe@random.com"}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcVGV4dDJQaG9uaWNzXFJlc3RBUElcYXBpXFVzZXJcUmVnaXN0ZXJVc2Vy?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, soapaction
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 19:52:43 GMT
Content-Length: 15

{"output":"-1"}
```

My error function is the one that fires, and here is the output:

console.log:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:57207/api/User/RegisterUser'."}
```

**Update:**

I was able to set the async to true and my new error message is this:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: Try setting datatype of the `$.ajax` to "application/json"

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky That did not make a difference. I still hit the error function.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead returning an `IHttpActionResult` or `IActionResult`, `Ok()` for a 200 response.

```
public IActionResult RegisterUser(JObject obj)
{
    RegisterUsers user = new RegisterUsers();
    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterUsers>(((JProperty)obj.First).Name);
    var temp = DataAccessLayer.RegisterUser(user.Username, user.Password, user.Firstname, user.Lastname, user.Email, null, null);
    JObject jobj = new JObject();
    jobj.Add("output", temp.ToString());

    return Ok(jobj);
}
```

If it continues to fail, try just return a simple string like `return Ok("Hello World!");`. If it succeeds with simple string, then the serialization of the object may be failing or is coming out as invalid JSON.

Comment: I tried returning an IHttpActionResult, but that failed. Returning a simple string also failed. I still have the same error as before: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:57207/api/User/RegisterUser'."}